# How to redirect to another ".cshtml" file in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, razor-pages

I'm new to asp.net core. I have created some razor pages and I want to redirect them by button click events. I have a login page, and I want to redirect to another cshtml page when user clicks on the submit button. This is my Login.cshtml code:

```
@page "/" 
@model Food_Reservation.Pages.Login.LoginModel

@{
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>صفحه ورود</title>

        <link href="~/css/Shared.css" , rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
        <link href="~/css/LoginCSS/Login.css" , rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
        <script src="~/js/Login/Login.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <form id="login-form" action="" method="post">
                
                <section id="userpass">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="userId">username</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="user-name"
                                   id="userId"
                                   class="ltr"
                                   required />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="password">password</label>
                            <input type="password"
                                   name="pass"
                                   id="password"
                                   class="ltr"
                                   required />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
    
                <section>
                    <button id="enter-btn" runat="server" onclick="RedirectPage();">Enter</button>
                </section>
    
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>

}
```

I have write some code in Login.cshtml.cs file, but not working:

```
namespace Food_Reservation.Pages.Login
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        public void RedirectPage()
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Food/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }

}
```

Also I write in javascript file:

```
void RedirectPage()
{
    return Redirect("~/Food/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Still not working...
What is wrong here?

I have tried to redirect to another ".cshtml" file, on click event of a button, but it didn't work.

I have tried to redirect from one ".cshtml" file to the other one, on a button click event, but it doesn't work. It again reloads the current page.

Comment: Without using client side code (jquery, javascript etc.) a click on the Submit button inside a form will call the Post action (OnPost, OnPostAsync) on the same code behind used to create the cshtml. So you need to have a OnPost method and a call to RedirectToPage. In client side code you use window.location to send your user the the page you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PageModel class, It will include an `OnGet()` method by default to load the page, Similar to `HttpGet` method in mvc. When you want to submit form in `Post` method, You need to use `OnPost()/OnPostAsync()` method to accept this http post request in `PageModel` class. In your Code, I think you wanna submit the form then do some actions finally redirect to another Razor page, So you can use `RedirectToPage("xx")` method.

```
public void OnGet()
{
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
     //other code

     //redirect to index.cshtml
     return RedirectToPage("pagename");
}
```

There are also some overloads.

[image]

More details you can refer to this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            return Redirect("/about");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(. It reload the current page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`<button id="enter-btn" runat="server" asp-page="~/Food/Index.cshtml">Enter</button>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).